# What may cause the coordinate in chaos of Ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, coordinates, ncurses

I developed a project in Ubuntu with the help of Ncurses: https://github.com/YvesZHI/FallingCode

Basically, it is very similar with `cmatrix`. It prints some characters dynamically on the terminal with the help of the API of Ncurses, such as `move()`, `printw()` etc. You can check them here: https://github.com/YvesZHI/FallingCode/blob/master/SysTool.cpp

It works locally but now I'm using MobaXterm to ssh on my Ubuntu remotely and if I execute my project, it seems that the coordinates are in chaos totally.

As you see, the characters appears but only at the very left side of the window.

What may cause this issue? Is it possible to fix this?

[image]

The output of `stty -a`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 42; columns 165; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

The output of `echo $TERM`:

```
xterm
```

Comment: I'm guessing your program is to blame. If I only could see it ... A [mcve] would be great! (focus on "minimal")

Comment: The most common reason for this is a wrong TERM setting.

Comment: Could you run "stty -a" and "echo $TERM" on the remote system through this MobaXterm ssh connection and [edit] your question to include the output?

Comment: @Kenster  I added the output in the post.

Comment: Remote tty thinks your screen is 165 columns wide? Maybe your terminal program is emulating a wide screen, and there's a way to scroll it left/right?

Comment: @Kenster Oh yeah, you are right. So in your opinion, which part causes this issue? My program? the Ubuntu settings? Or the MobaXterm?